# error while Translate the model for the Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am new to Autodesk viewer. I tried to show my Revit model on the viewer by following [this tutorial](https://autodesk-forge.github.io/?GettingStarted#three)
I have done 3 first step successfully but when I try to Translate my model for the Viewer I get this error: `"diagnostic":"Failed to trigger translation for this file`. Can you tell me what I did wrong ? here is what I have done:

Client ID
bfmqewJQXEA1ldJ1HIA6jjLzgcICbieq
Client Secret
IoswWNleEudR8gcz

---

```
curl https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate \
  --data 'client_id=bfmqewJQXEA1ldJ1HIA6jjLzgcICbieq&client_secret=IoswWNleEudR8gcz&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read%20data:write%20bucket:create' \
  --header 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -k
```

---

```
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJiZm1xZXdKUVhFQTFsZEoxSElBNmpqTHpnY0lDYmllcSIsImV4cCI6MTUzNjUyNjU1OCwic2NvcGUiOlsiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImJ1Y2tldDpjcmVhdGUiXSwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20vYXVkL2p3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiZzRlVllLcjQxeDMxczBxMGhVWVgyNDdnWjJWcElqOGlpT1dyVmw5aGZKV1Z0MzRYaENHSXNZeU1lcWhCS1pqRSJ9.DvQUREsLvPVwODfIxkNrWeeDoUK_b89aAEE2pbpUcv0","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599}
```

---

```
curl 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJiZm1xZXdKUVhFQTFsZEoxSElBNmpqTHpnY0lDYmllcSIsImV4cCI6MTUzNjUyNjU1OCwic2NvcGUiOlsiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImJ1Y2tldDpjcmVhdGUiXSwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20vYXVkL2p3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiZzRlVllLcjQxeDMxczBxMGhVWVgyNDdnWjJWcElqOGlpT1dyVmw5aGZKV1Z0MzRYaENHSXNZeU1lcWhCS1pqRSJ9.DvQUREsLvPVwODfIxkNrWeeDoUK_b89aAEE2pbpUcv0' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"bucketKey":"mecroomboiler","policyKey":"transient"}' -k
```

---

```
{"bucketKey":"mecroomboiler","bucketOwner":"bfmqewJQXEA1ldJ1HIA6jjLzgcICbieq","createdDate":1536523047527,"permissions":[{"authId":"bfmqewJQXEA1ldJ1HIA6jjLzgcICbieq","access":"full"}],"policyKey":"transient"}
```

---

```
    curl 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mecroomboiler/objects/fulestoragesss' \
      -X 'PUT' -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJiZm1xZXdKUVhFQTFsZEoxSElBNmpqTHpnY0lDYmllcSIsImV4cCI6MTUzNjUyNjU1OCwic2NvcGUiOlsiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImJ1Y2tldDpjcmVhdGUiXSwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20vYXVkL2p3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiZzRlVllLcjQxeDMxczBxMGhVWVgyNDdnWjJWcElqOGlpT1dyVmw5aGZKV1Z0MzRYaENHSXNZeU1lcWhCS1pqRSJ9.DvQUREsLvPVwODfIxkNrWeeDoUK_b89aAEE2pbpUcv0' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' -T '/home/mohsen/Desktop/FU-001.rvt' -k
```

---

```
"bucketKey" : "mecroomboiler",
  "objectId" : "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mecroomboiler/fulestoragesss",
  "objectKey" : "fulestoragesss",
  "sha1" : "17ad2e118c564b6e22fde54959db9859c43af42c",
  "size" : 71889,
  "contentType" : "application/octet-stream",
  "location" : "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mecroomboiler/objects/fulestoragesss"
```

---

```
urn : dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bWVjcm9vbWJvaWxlci9mdWxlc3RvcmFnZXNzcw==
```

---

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJiZm1xZXdKUVhFQTFsZEoxSElBNmpqTHpnY0lDYmllcSIsImV4cCI6MTUzNjUyNjU1OCwic2NvcGUiOlsiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImJ1Y2tldDpjcmVhdGUiXSwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20vYXVkL2p3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiZzRlVllLcjQxeDMxczBxMGhVWVgyNDdnWjJWcElqOGlpT1dyVmw5aGZKV1Z0MzRYaENHSXNZeU1lcWhCS1pqRSJ9.DvQUREsLvPVwODfIxkNrWeeDoUK_b89aAEE2pbpUcv0' 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
  -d '{"input":{"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bWVjcm9vbWJvaWxlci9mdWxlc3RvcmFnZXNzcw"},"output":{"formats":[{"type":"svf","views":["2d,3d"]}]}}' -k
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome on SO. This question is rather hard to digest. If you want people to help you here, please consider helping them understanding your problem by following their [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and formatting your post with [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to ease reading :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog post that takes you through the process of achieving the uploading and translation of the file to SVF.

Here it is. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/tutorial-using-curl-2-legged-authentication-model-translation